# Password protection for VBA

Tags: vba

I just want to understand is there any way to protect my VBA code password from Bypass.

Is there any why that my macro file or the VBA password cannot be compromised.
Or if compromise I got the notification something??

Answer (score 0):

No. While you can password protect your VBA Code you cannot gurantee that noone else can bypass your password. There are several tools online which can easily do this for you.

The only thing which can help protect your code is a process called "obfuscation" where you basically rename all variables to complete nonsense names and masking strings which makes understanding your code a lot harder. (There are also several tools online (for example CrunchCode) which do this for you).